# Change a Zend_Form_Element_Select to a Zend_Form_Element_Hidden based on it's values

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

In Zend Framework I'm trying to create a select element that will automatically turn into a hidden element if there is only one item the user can select.  I want it to behave just like a Select element if it has more than one value so I know that I need to extend the class using the following:

```
class Application_Form_Element_SingleSelect extends Zend_Form_Element_Select{}
```

But I'm not sure how to get it to output as a hidden element.

**Update**

This was the final code I came up with:

```
public function render(Zend_View_Interface $view = null){
    $options = $this->getMultiOptions();

    // check to see if there is only one option
    if(count($options)!=1){
        // render the view
        return parent::render($view);
    }

    // start building up the hidden element
    $returnVal = '<input type="hidden" name="' . $this->getName() . '" ';

    // set the current value
    $keys = array_keys($options);
    $returnVal .= 'value="' . $keys[0] . '" ';

    // get the attributes
    $attribs = $this->getAttribs();

    // check to see if this has a class
    if(array_key_exists('class', $attribs)){
        $returnVal .= 'class="' . $attribs['class'] . '" ';
    }

    // check to see if this has an id
    if(array_key_exists('id', $attribs)){
        $returnVal .= 'id="' . $attribs['id'] . '" ';
    } else {
        $returnVal .= 'id="' . $this->getName() . '" ';
    }

    return $returnVal . '>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to override render method which is responsible for generating html through all decorators added to that element .

```
class Application_Form_Element_SingleSelect extends Zend_Form_Element_Select{

 public function render(Zend_View_Interface $view = null)
{
  $options = $this->getMultiOptions();
   return count($options) > 1 ? parent::render($view) : '' ;
}

}
```